# Handsontable copy/paste hidden data

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm using Handsontable with objects as the data backing. The data looks something like this:

```
[
  { productId: 1, productName: "Shirt", productType: "Clothing" }
  { productId: 2, productName: "Pants", productType: "Clothing" }
]
```

The Handsontable columns configuration looks like this:

```
columns: [
  { data: "productName" },
  { data: "productType" }
]
```

So the `productId` field is not included in the table, or in other words, the `productId` column is hidden.

When the user highlights a row in the table and presses Ctrl+C, then Ctrl+V in another row, only `productName` and `productType` are transferred to the new row. `productId` is not copied, but I want it to be. **How can I make Handsontable copy the hidden data in addition to the visible data?**

I have looked into including the `productId` field in the table, but hiding it with css. This used to be the only way to have hidden data in Handsontable, as you can see in [this thread](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/120). But none of those solutions seem to work very well. I have also considered modifying what gets copied using a beforeCellCopy event, as in [this thread](https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/pull/1856). But that is a very hacky and ugly way to solve this problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: You can bind a toString method to all of your objects, i did this, but now i cant paste data. Trying to sort it out too.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to copy paste it outside of Handsontable, I presume. That means you want to add content to your clipboard beyond what a CTRL+C event would normally do. This means you have to get nasty regardless so a `beforeCellCopy` event sounds like a perfect idea.

The only other thing you could do is to capture the key strokes event yourself, stop propagation, and use the clipboard plugin to send it whatever data you want. This one may be cleaner but it involves working with the clipboard plugin.